# Windows 7 Search By Filename

Tags: windows-7, windows-search

I'm getting better at understanding the Windows7 search, but am still not happy with it.  Is there a way to search for all filenames that end with a certain extension?  If I search on

> filename:*.ext

I get results like this:

> file.ext
>
> file.ext.doc
>
> ext.txt

I just want to find

> file.ext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tested this and if you use  `"*.ext"` it'll only return files with `.ext` at the END of the file name.
So it'll still return `.doc.ext`  but not `.ext.doc.`

Comment: Thanks.  Adding the quotes seems obvious now, but since we didn't have to do that in previous Windows searches, it's not something that comes to mind right away.  I really don't like this new search.  :(

Answer (score 5):

Another method is to use the option **ext:***extension*.

Comment: For example
ext:.doc